# Join SQL tables by id field

Tags: php, sql, join

I have the following sql query on a mysql db which returns all results from wp_client where the form_id is 46 and the date_created is within the last 7 days...

```
SELECT *
FROM
    wp_client WHERE form_id = '46'
and
    cast(date_created as date) >= current_date - interval '7' day
```

I have another table wp_client_detail that stores more information that I would like to be included in the results.  The field client_id in wp_client_detail matches up with the field id in wp_client.

I assume I need to use a JOIN command but can't work out how, I have tried...

```
    INNER JOIN
            wp_client_detail
        ON
            wp_client.id=wp_CLIENT_detail.lead_id;
```

But it's not working, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your syntax, just make sure you have it all in the right order:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    wp_client 
    INNER JOIN wp_client_detail ON
            wp_client.id=wp_CLIENT_detail.lead_id
WHERE form_id = '46'
and  cast(date_created as date) >= current_date - interval '7' day;
```

If that syntax doesnt work, then I would suggest that you have problems with your data.

This can also be rendered with an `IN`

```
select
  *
from
  wp_client c
where
  form_id = '46'
  and cast(date_created as date) >= current_date - interval '7' day
  id in (select lead_id from wp_CLIENT_detail)
```

Or `EXISTS`:

```
select
  *
from
  wp_client c
where
  form_id = '46'
  and cast(date_created as date) >= current_date - interval '7' day
  id exists (select 1 from wp_CLIENT_detail d where c.id = d.lead_id)
```

Comment: It is returning an empty array for me with the INNER JOIN included, must be an issue with my data somewhere

Comment: Yes.. if you change the inner join to a left join, you can get a sense of what data is not joining.

Comment: Strange, still nothing at all with a left join

Comment: Maybe not strange... the where clause is probably making it a default inner join.  I've added in and exists examples, just look at your data, start selecting individual records that are in one set and seeing if they are in the other.